# what is the correct way to add ajax url?

Tags: javascript, controllers, url, ajax, base-url

My controller file is

**Vendor/MultipleCustomerAccount/Controller/Account/LogoutPost.php**

what should be the ajax url?

Comment: I think you are asking for how to call a controller.
This article can help you https://magefan.com/blog/first-controller-in-magento-2

Comment: no I want to get some dynamic data from controller in js file. For that we use ajax right? in that ajax call how should we use the url?

Answer (score 1):

To access the controller URL, it's more like a formula = route name or front name you give in the routes.xml file / Controller Path / Controller File name, so when we apply this formula to your controller it should be "local.magento.com/routename/account/logoutpost", Please note: I do not know what is the front name you are using so try replacing that with your actual, hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: kumar ... thanks for the reply.But  I think you are using font instead of frontend here.

Comment: @MohmadAshikMA Have edited thanks for the suggestion, If this post helped you please do give a like, as this helps motivate to post such answers. Thanks have a nice day.